# Integer based idexing of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make my code work regardless of whether a dataframe is supplied an index using its string label or by position.

While using the column label works fine in the following context, my attempts to use an integer have so far failed.

```
if(isinstance(person_index, int)):
    people['p_series'] = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[df['ID']==sample][person_index]) # This fails
people['p_series'] = pd.DataFrame(df[df['ID']==sample][person_index]) # This works
```

I get the error message

> iLocation based boolean indexing cannot use an indexable as a mask

Attempting to index without iloc

```
pd.DataFrame(df[df['ID']==sample][person_index])
```

or with loc

```
pd.DataFrame(df.loc[df['ID']==sample][person_index])
```

Produces the error message

> KeyError: 0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the dataframe `df` looks like, but considering e.g.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [111, 111, 222],
    'first_name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Joe'],
    'last_name': ['Doe', 'Doe', 'Schmoe']})
print(df)
```

we have

```
    ID first_name last_name
0  111       John       Doe
1  111       Jane       Doe
2  222        Joe    Schmoe
```

Then,

```py
sample=111
person_index=0
print(df[df['ID']==sample])
```

results in

```
    ID first_name last_name
0  111       John       Doe
1  111       Jane       Doe
```

and

```py
print(df[df['ID']==sample].iloc[person_index])
```

results in

```
ID             111
first_name    John
last_name      Doe
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

However, if the `.iloc` is moved to the beginning:

```py
print(df.iloc[df['ID']==sample][person_index])
```

the result is similar to what you mentioned: `NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available`